# Select totals to return only one record in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

After spending more than 3 hours on this I gave up.

I have four tables:

```
Users, Approvals, Centers, Managements
```

My ultimate goal is to get the total number of users in each management separated by the user role (I have two roles here : Parents and Society members)

I've been using the following code

```
select 
    (select count(r.StudentId) 
     from Users u 
     where u.UserId = r.StudentId and u.RoleId = 10) as Parents,
    (select count(r.StudentId) 
     from Users u  
     where u.UserId = r.StudentId and u.RoleId = 11) as SocietyMembers,
    e.ManagementId, e.ManagmentTitle
from 
    CentersRegistrationsApprovals r --ON r.StudentId = u.UserId
inner join
    Centers c ON c.CenterId = r.CenterId
inner join
    Managments e ON e.ManagementId = c.EducationManagementId
group by 
    e.ManagementId, e.ManagmentTitle, StudentId
```

I'm expecting the query result to be as the following :

```
Parents   SocietyMambers   ManagementId   ManagementName
----------------------------------------------------------------
3         3                10             North Region
```

However the result set always gives me

```
Parents   SocietyMambers   ManagementId   ManagementName
----------------------------------------------------------------
3         NULL             10             North Region
NULL      3                10             North Region
```

Any ideas how to consolidate the result to only 1 record?

Comment: remove group by by studentid

Comment: @KannanKandasamy then you can't use it in SELECT clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try something like this (not tested)

```
; with CTE1 as (
    select 
        (select count(r.StudentId) 
         from Users u 
         where u.UserId = r.StudentId and u.RoleId = 10) as Parents,
        (select count(r.StudentId) 
         from Users u  
         where u.UserId = r.StudentId and u.RoleId = 11) as SocietyMembers,
        e.ManagementId, e.ManagmentTitle
    from 
        CentersRegistrationsApprovals r --ON r.StudentId = u.UserId
    inner join
        Centers c ON c.CenterId = r.CenterId
    inner join
        Managments e ON e.ManagementId = c.EducationManagementId
    group by 
        e.ManagementId, e.ManagmentTitle, StudentId
)
SELECT MAX(Parents), MAX(SocietyMembers), ManagementId, StudentId
FROM CTE1
GROUP BY ManagementId, StudentId
```

Comment: There is no studentID in CTE1 results is there?  So wouldn't the query against CTE1 fail?

Comment: just remove StudentId from the select and groupBy it will work fine

Answer (score 2):

You can query like below:

```
select 
     Sum(case when u.roleId = 10 then 1 else 0 end) as Parents,
     Sum(case when u.roleId = 11 then 1 else 0 end) as SocietyMembers,
     e.ManagementId, e.ManagmentTitle
from 
    CentersRegistrationsApprovals r --ON r.StudentId = u.UserId
inner join
    Centers c ON c.CenterId = r.CenterId
inner join
    Managments e ON e.ManagementId = c.EducationManagementId
Join Users u ON r.StudentId = u.UserId
group by 
    e.ManagementId, e.ManagmentTitle
```

Comment: Your solution is working but I'm going to test it thoroughly thanks anyway